# mb_substr() from json_decode()'d emoji

Tags: php, encoding, telegram

I have the following JSON: `"\ud83e\uddea test"`, that is decoded to  `test` via `json_decode()`.

I need extract the word `test`, so I received the *offset* `3` and *length* `4`.

You should note that it is possible to "see" this in the JSON encoding itself, if we consider that each `\uXXXX` is a single character: `"<offset 0>\ud83e<offset 1>\uddea<offset 2> <offset 3>test"`.

The problem is that after I run `json_decode()`, functions like `mb_substr()`, `iconv_substr()`, `substr()`, so on, consider that the emoji have a single character. In fact, it does. The problem is that I receive the *offset* as `3` from an external source (is a [Telegram entity](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity)).

I have tried to change it to a lot of encodings, but without success.

```php
$input = ' test';

$encoded = json_encode($input); // => "\ud83e\uddea test"
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);

$substr = substr($decoded, 3, 4);
$mb_substr = mb_substr($decoded, 3, 4);
$iconv_substr = iconv_substr($decoded, 3, 4);

var_dump(compact(
    'encoded', 
    'decoded', 
    'substr',       // "� te" (fail)
    'mb_substr',    // "est" (fail)
    'iconv_substr'  // "est" (fail)
));
```

**Edit:**

I have found a workaround by using BIG-5 encoding, but I don't know how reliable it is:

```php
$input = ' test';

var_dump(mb_substr($input, 3, 4, 'BIG-5')); // => "test"
```

Comment: The documentation says the offset is given in _“UTF-16 code units to the start of the entity”_. If I use `mb_convert_encoding` to convert the decoded JSON value to `UTF-16` first, and then use `mb_substr($data, 2, null, 'UTF-16')`, the result is `test` (as an 8 byte long UTF-16 string, so you’d probably have to convert back to UTF-8 then.) Using `2` here seems kinda logical to me, because when they say this is the offset in UTF-16 code units, if I am interpreting this correctly, would mean `3` refers to the _third_ character, but since PHP counts from 0, it has to be reduced by one.

Comment: Not a 100% sure on that last part, a few more examples of input data with such a special character in different positions/more than one, could probably help verify that.

Comment: @CBroe not necessarily. The information that comes from the entity is `3`, really. Because it is considered that the emoji is composed of **2 characters** of **2 bytes each**, and considering the _space_, we have `3` characters before `"test"`. While PHP understands that the emoji is a **4-byte character** (which makes a lot more sense to me). Basically, I think it is much more of a problem in how Telegram sends information to us (which I believe to be incorrect) than the fact that PHP is unable to process this way.

Comment: I'd say that you understand it in the wrong way adhering your consideration about `UTF-16`. I'm pretty sure that internal character encoding (`mb_internal_encoding()`) is `UTF-8`. Hence, `substr($decoded, 5, 4)` or `mb_substr($decoded, 2, 4)` or `iconv_substr($decoded, 2, 4)` should extract the word `test`. However, `substr` is the worst, IMHO.

Comment: @JosefZ actually, any encoding will not works. See: https://3v4l.org/I3lr4

Comment: Again: I'm recommending `mb_substr($decoded, 2, 4)` and you insist on _wrong_ `mb_substr($decoded, 3, 4)`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @JosefZ as I mentioned in the post, the information comes directly from Telegram itself, such as *offset* `3` and *length* `4`, and is based on what the user is sending to the chat. So I have no control to modify this information and I need to extract the data with it. Through a workaround with `json_encode()` I can do, but it is something very complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got wise to it, eventually: *given* string, offset and length where

```
offset   Integer   Offset in UTF-16 code units to the start of the entity
length   Integer   Length of the entity in UTF-16 code units
```

```
<?php

function telegram_substr ( $str, $offset, $length) {
    $bmp = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i++ ) {
        $mb_substr = mb_substr( $str, $i, 1 );
        $mb_ord    = mb_ord( $mb_substr );
        $bmp[] = $mb_substr;
        if ( $mb_ord > 0xFFFF ) {
            $bmp[] = '';
        }
    }
    return implode( "", array_slice( $bmp, $offset, $length));
} // telegram_substr

$input = ' test ﬀψ';

$xxx = telegram_substr ( $input, 3, 4);
echo $xxx .' ['. telegram_substr ( $input, 3, 7) ."]\n";

?>
```

**Output**: `.\SO\66808885.php`

```
test [test ]
```